# Calculating percentages for sub-groups in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'group':['A','A','A','A','A',
                            'B','B','B','B','B',
                            'C','C','C','C','C'],
                  'category': ['zero','first', 'second', 'first+second', 'total',
                               'zero', 'first', 'second', 'first+second', 'total',
                               'zero','first', 'second', 'first+second', 'total'],
                  'sales': [50,100,75,175,225, 
                            5,10,15,25,30,
                            1000,2000,3000,3000,4000]})
```

I am trying to calculate the `%` of each category inside a group, the problem is that `category` `first+second` and `total` is a sum of previous categories and should not be taken in to calculations.

I tried:

```
df['%'] = (df['sales'] / df.groupby(['group'])['sales'].transform('sum')) * 100
```

But now `total` is only 36% where it should be 100% and then then whole percentages are wrong.
If I isolate the groups like so:

```
my_df['%_v2'] =(my_df['sales'] / my_df[my_df.category.isin(['zero', 'first', 'second'])].groupby(['group'])['sales'].transform('sum')) * 100
```

Then `zero, first, second` `%` are correct, but I get `nan` in `first+second` and `total`:

[image]

Instead of `nan` I would like to get the percentages of `(175/225) * 100` for `first+second` and `225/225` for `total`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Idea is replace not matched values by `NaN` in [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html):

```
s = (df['sales'].where(df.category.isin(['zero', 'first', 'second']))
                .groupby(df['group'])
                .transform('sum'))

df['%'] = df['sales'].div(s).mul(100)
print (df)
   group      category  sales           %
0      A          zero     50   22.222222
1      A         first    100   44.444444
2      A        second     75   33.333333
3      A  first+second    175   77.777778
4      A         total    225  100.000000
5      B          zero      5   16.666667
6      B         first     10   33.333333
7      B        second     15   50.000000
8      B  first+second     25   83.333333
9      B         total     30  100.000000
10     C          zero   1000   16.666667
11     C         first   2000   33.333333
12     C        second   3000   50.000000
13     C  first+second   3000   50.000000
14     C         total   4000  100.000000
```